# EF 6 using TPT error both have the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have one big question about TPT + EF6.

At my DB model I have one table `Person` (basic information of persons in my application) and I have tables for `Supplier` and `Consumer`.

My classes are:

```
//to table dbo.Person
public class Person 
{
    public long Id {get; set;} //is pk
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

//to table dbo.Supplier
public class Supplier : Person
{
    public long Id {get; set;}//is pk and fk
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
}

//to table dbo.Consumer
public class Consumer 
{
    public long Id {get; set;} //is pk and fk
    public string budget {get; set;}
}
```

If I have one person that is both supplier and consumer, and I get the records from same/different `DBContext` or navigate form another Entitys, then EF throws an exception:

> All objects in the EntitySet `Person` must have unique primary keys. However, an instance of type `Supplier`and an instance of type `Consumer` both have the same primary key value, `EntitySet=Person;ID=20`.

Is there a way to specify one discriminator in TPT inheritance?
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you found a solution to this issue ?

Comment: Does the `consumer` class not inherit from Person? When I copy the code to a solution, I get an warning that the `Id` property from `Supplier` hides the `Id` property from `Person`. Why can`t you just remove the `Id` in the derived class? The `Person` class cannot be abstract?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADO.NET Entity Framework: Can I have multiple entity types for the same row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630045/ado-net-entity-framework-can-i-have-multiple-entity-types-for-the-same-row)

Comment: Discriminators belong to TPH,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the pattern you actually need is Table Per Concrete Class

[image: as illustrated by this SQL Server diagram]

This can be achieved by

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public  Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public  Consumer Consumer { get; set; }


}

public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Budget { get; set; }
}
```

Remember to put the following in your dbcontext

```
  public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Consumer> Consumers { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Person>  People { get; set; }
```