# All objects in the EntitySet must have unique primary > keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I am facing an issue with entity framework code first and inheritance. Here’s my model :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    // Student properties
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    // Teacher properties
}
```

Those 3 classes are mapped to 3 tables with entity framework. Each of them has a column « Id » (Table per type).
So far, this is working well.

The problem is that **a Student can also be a Teacher**. 
When I try to get both the Student and the Teacher objects in the same DbContext, I get the error :

> All objects in the EntitySet 'Context.People' must have unique primary
>   keys. However, an instance of type 'Student' and an instance of type
>   Teacher' both have the same primary key value.

Is there a way to work around this problem ?

EDIT : Here's more details about my code :

```
using(var context = new CoreContext())
{
    var testStudents = context.Students.ToList();
    var testTeachers = context.Teachers.ToList();
}
```

*(Error happens when context.Teachers.ToList() is called).*

```
public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherMap());
    }
}

internal class PersonMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonMap() 
    {
        this.HasKey(i => i.Id);
        this.Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(i => i.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.ToTable("People");
    }
}

internal class StudentMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public StudentMap() 
    {
        this.ToTable("Students");
    }
}

internal class TeacherMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Teacher>
{
    public TeacherMap() 
    {
        this.ToTable("Teachers");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you're doing in the DbContext. Please, so the code, and say when that error happens. I think it has nothing to do with the model, but what with you're doing

Comment: Why are you trying to return BOTH the student and teacher objects for the same person? Aren't you really concerned with just one or the other at any given time?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers. @JotaBe I've just updated my question. The error happens when context.Teachers.ToList() is called.

Comment: @W3AVE Yes, I am trying to get BOTH the student and the teacher objects for the same person. I will need it for a Course for example (get the Course, with the associated Teachers and Students).

Comment: @MrMelodie Could you get a fix for your case? I'm facing the same problem that you and I can't find a solution. I wish I could avoid using `Table-per-hierarchy model`.

Comment: @RuelRamosRibeiro Unfortunately, no, I could not get a fix for that case. I am not sure that there is one. I had to change my model so I stopped looking for a solution. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADO.NET Entity Framework: Can I have multiple entity types for the same row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630045/ado-net-entity-framework-can-i-have-multiple-entity-types-for-the-same-row)

Comment: @Korayem. This is not a duplicate. The other case is a single table for all kind of entities. Here there is a table for each entity. Besides, the main problem is still there: as you can read in the linked answer: "no record for one person can have more than one concrete type when materialized", which is the problem stated in this question. The problem is that you cannot have two entities in a single row (of a single or several joined tables)

Answer (score 1):

This can only happen if your DB contains a row in the `People` table that is joined both to `Student` and `Teacher` tables. To discover this offending row (or rows) run this query in your database:

```
Select P.Id 
from People P
left join Students S on P.Id = S.Id
left join Teachers T on P.Id = T.Id
where S.Id is not null and T.Id is not null
```

If this query returns entries, they must have been created directly in the DB. EF can't have done it.

Explanation: with your inheritance hierarchy, a person (row of `People`) can either be a `Student` or a `Teacher` but not both at the same time. However, there is nothing in the satabase that avoids this to happen. It must have been created directly in the DB as test data, or it was created with a different inheritance hierarchy, which was later changed.

Comment: Actually yes, that’s the aim of my question. I do have Students that also are Teachers and I don’t know how to manage this kind of inheritance with entity framework.
I must precise that I am working with an existing database (the datas where not generated by entity framework). 
Do you see what I am trying to do ?

Comment: That's a new question. Please, add it as a new question, not as a comment. And perhaps someone knows an answer. Let me think of it...

Answer (score 0):

you may need to specify a little more like that

```
public Abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public class CoreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentMap());
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherMap());
    }
}




var testStudents = context.Person.OfType<Students>().ToList();
 var testTeachers = context.Person.OfType<Teacher>().ToList();
```